# Time-Based workflow Scheduled date Changing?

Tags: admin

based workflow that will create a task. I scheduled the task creation to `1 Hour After Rule Trigger Date` for testing purposes. The task creation is in time-based-workflow monitoring so I'm sure that It entered the workflow rule and just waiting for the task creation. Now my issue is, the scheduled date is changing and extending thus not creating the task, Any idea why this is happening?

I also checked the trigger and other workflow rules, it seems like it doesn't affect my issue.

Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if it is hitting the limit of 1000 time triggers per hour  which is why it might be moving to the next batch. Check the content marked in bold.

From one of the Salesforce knowledge article

Time based workflow actions will not always execute at the exact time displayed in the Monitoring setup menu instead, they are batched and executed every 15 minutes. Therefore the expectation for the execution of time based workflow actions should be within 15 minutes of the scheduled time **unless the Time Trigger per hour limit is exceeded, which will push the batch to the next hour.**

Comment: I'm checking the time-based workflow list and it's the only execution that's needed to run.

Comment: I'm also checking the related record that triggered the workflow, It's not being updated by any trigger. The issue is , the scheduled date is being extended thus task is not being created @VijayGanji